# Access Property from application.yml in Micronaut

Tags: gatling, micronaut

I am trying to access a property from my application.yml file in my Gatling Simulation class. I am using Micronaut Framework.

My application.yml is as follows:

```
gatling:
  url: 'http://google.com'
```

My attempts to get the value are as follows:

Attempt 1:

```
@Value("${gatling.url}")
String url;
```

Attempt 2:

```
@Property(name = "gatling.url");
String url;
```

But both these attempts return NPE.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way this can work. Gatling Simulations are instantiated by its own engine, not by Micronaut and its dependency injection module.

Comment: Then how can I inject a property in Gatling Simulation?

Comment: I used Java options to inject environment variable to Gatling environment. If anyone has a better Idea, please let me know.

Comment: "I used Java options to inject environment variable to Gatling environment. If anyone has a better Idea, please let me know." - If you can inject an environment variable into the environment then you can use something like  `@Value("${your.environment.variable}")` to inject the `YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` environment variable value into a property in a Micronaut managed bean.